# mysql how to get the minimum id of child by querying the parent

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

I have one table called

**editoriale**

containing titles and text-contents and one table

**editoriale_foto**

that contains the pictures of the before mentioned editoriale.

I would like to query

"editoriale"

AND have also a cover image (it could be ok the first one entered - so the minimum id relative to that editorial).

I am lost in queries.

I have tried this one, but I get a lot of images and i need just one.

```
 SELECT e.*,ef.foto FROM editoriale e INNER JOIN editoriale_foto ef ON ef.editoriale = e.id ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Comment: I have tried this one: SELECT e.*,ef.foto FROM editoriale e INNER JOIN editoriale_foto ef ON ef.editoriale = e.id GROUP BY ef.editoriale ORDER BY e.id DESC  . It works, but it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Dont order by descending, order by ascending if you want the lowest id first. If you want only one row add in `limit 1`.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you want 1 row from editoriale in the result, or many rows? The latter requires a more complex query to get the first editoriale_photo.

Comment: please see accepted answer. It is exactly what I meant. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM editoriale_foto ef
LEFT JOIN editoriale e ON ef.editoriale = e.id
```

gives you whole list of fotos and connected to them editoriales.

If you need to select only first photo for each editoriale you can do sth like this:

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM editoriale_foto
GROUP BY editoriale
```

So in result you may use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM editoriale_foto ef
LEFT JOIN editoriale e ON ef.editoriale = e.id
WHERE ef.id IN (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM editoriale_foto
    GROUP BY editoriale
)
```

Comment: IT'S PERFECT!. Thank you for the detailed answer.